# Adding Video as a splash in storyboard ios7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I want to show a video at the beginning of the application start, just like a splash. My whole app will be in Navigation. First, i add the video in a splashViewController and set it in appDelegate as rootView and then simply set the mainViewController as rootView again.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    splashViewController = [[SplashViewController alloc] init];
    splashViewController = (SplashViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SplashViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = splashViewController;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:9.0 target:self selector:@selector(removeSplashScreen:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    return YES;
}

-(void)removeSplashScreen:(id)userInfo
{
    [splashViewController removeFromParentViewController];

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    mainViewController = (MainViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
}
```

Now i want to start navigation from this mainViewController. I use storyBoard & add navigation from `Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller` in mainViewController. Don't do it programmatically. But i know the way of implementing it using Nib.xib. Here i also put the `arrow`(The arrow which indicate the starting VC) mark besides of it. But it getting crash when i click a button from mainVC to go next VC. How can i set the navigation here?

If any one have the answer, please share with me. Thanks a lot in Advance.

The scenario of my storyboard:

[image]

Comment: If you read the Apple Human Interface guide you will see that splash screen are not recommended it. There are no notion such as splash screens, but launch image instead. Keep in mind that not following the guide could lead to app rejection

Comment: Thanks for commenting and remind the guide line. But i want to do it as that way. In past in nib file i do apps with video splash & app store never reject it.

Comment: I agree with `meda` not sticking to the guidelines will get your app rejected. Although what you are after doesn't go against the guidelines as this is just a `UIViewController` that plays a video. So from my understanding your app will launch, the user will see the launch image, then the first view controller to present itself will be the `SplashViewController`. There doesn't seem to be anything from with that, I will however note that this has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE` so please don't use that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

happy to help you here in two steps

step 1-
       your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions code is almost correct , but it does not matter if its working . so let focus on step two.

step 2-  in -(void)removeSplashScreen:(id)userInfo

```
   -first line is good , but you even dont need it because you are going to switch the   root controller (leave it for now)
   - second line (no need to write it)
   - third line is really bad , what you  doing here is trying to alloc you mainviewcontroller. really you need it with storyboard? no 
   - you should load you main view controller from storyboard
   MainViewController* mainViewController = (MainViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];
```

"this line is enough to load your main view controller from storyboard"
      -next line is correct
      self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
      code seems to be working now , but still you are missing navigation controller because you have loaded mainviewcontroller from storyboard, not the navigation controller.

```
- two solution for it
1- load navigation controller in place of mainviewcontroller(give a storyboard id to navigation controller , load it , and make it as root controller) --i will always go with it
2- make a navigation controller with allocating it & make its rootviewcontroller the mainviewcontroller
```

-----------------working code ---------------

Comment: Thanks a lot pawan. It is working :). I go for your 2nd solution. >> "2- make a navigation controller with allocating it & make its rootviewcontroller the mainviewcontroller", but here will be a little edit. which is "2- make a navigation controller with allocating it & make its rootviewcontroller the navigationController". Thanks a lot for your explanation & giving choice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok Despite my advice (in the comments), here is how you can achieve this:

**Display splash:**

```
//StoryBoard
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard 
                                   storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
//Splash Controller                                
SplashViewController *splashViewController = [mainStoryboard 
                instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SplashViewController"];
//Show it                                 
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:splashViewController 
                                             animated:NO completion:nil];
```

**Remove it:**

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

---

EDIT: Still not working?

Maybe you called it to quick. do this:

**viewDidLoad**:

```
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:9.0 
                                    target:self 
                                  selector:@selector(removeSplashScreen:) 
                                  userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

**function to remove:**

```
-(void)removeSplashScreen:(id)userInfo
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Whilst I agree with your advice what they are trying to achieve isn't going against it. The guidelines refer to the launch image what happens after is up to you (per-say) so adding a view controller (as that is all it is) that plays a video is perfectly acceptable nowhere does it say that isn't allowed.

Comment: Yes. That's my point. It is not like i am not adding any splash here. I did. But after that just want to add a splashVC. That's it.

Comment: yeah you guys are right , who am I to judge anyway.

Comment: It showing error pointing at "dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES" & says "No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector 'dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:'" meda

Comment: @Tulon yes exactly like Popeye said show it in `AppDelegate` , hide it in `SplashViewController`

Comment: No luck man. Now it is not showing the mainVC at all only the splashViewController. :(

I add the picture of my storyboard. So that it makes you a clear sense.

Comment: No dear, as i previously said, in appDelegate >> "dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES" shows an error. I think before implementing "Navigation" the file can't recognize the Navigation property which is "dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES" here.
By the way thanks a lot again to you both meda & Popeye for a fruitful conversation. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

So the solution, according to pawan's given answer is :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    splashViewController = (SplashViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SplashViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = splashViewController;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:9.0 target:self selector:@selector(removeSplashScreen:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    return YES;
}

-(void)removeSplashScreen:(id)userInfo
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    mainViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    mainViewController = (MainViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];

    navigationContoller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationContoller;
}
```

:)